# Dynamically create graphql query based on criterias from javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql, bigcommerce

I am using GraphQl together with bigcommerce to grab products, and i need to find a sollution to make my query dynamic - its based on the length of an array of SKU's. Its no problem to make it work with one product.

```
let query = `
 query getProductBySku($sku: String) {
  site {
   product(sku: $sku) {
    id
    entityId
    name
    sku
    }
   }
  }
 `
```

And i figured out so far that i need to use something like aliases in graphql to be able to get several products in several response like this

```
 query productById {
  site {
   o1: product(entityId: 167) {
    id
    entityId
    sku
    name
   }
  o2: product(entityId: 168 ) {
   id
   entityId
   sku
   name
  }
 }
}
```

But i need to be able to make this alias query dynamic based on the lenght of the array. How would you approach to solve this problem? Is it possible to maybe create a loop that will write out the query before i will run it. Any help to let me in the right direction here would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

ps. im using javascript.

Comment: Better solution: change the api so that it accepts an array of `entityIds` and returns multiple `products` at once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone curious i ended up being able to use .map to dynamically loop out the query and the run it :)

```
let query = `
 query productBySku {
  site {
   ${sku
    .map(
      (product: any, idx: number) =>
       `pro${idx}: product(sku: "${product}") {
       id
       entityId
       sku
       name
      }
     `
    )
  .join('')}
 }
}
```

`

Comment: You might want to use a fragment for all the fields shared between these.